# Deep-linking and routing in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

As mentioned in the title, I'm trying to redirect a link if the user logged in, if not, it will go to log in page then redirect if successful.

I need to redirect to this link. It has some params

```
http://sample.com/?itemid=HFJD867&mode=normal
```

the problem is when I tried visiting the url, the link will be like this

```
http://sample.com/?itemid=HFJD867&mode=normal/#!/login
```

this is ok at this point since the login page still appears.

then once I've successfully logged in, it will be

```
http://sample.com/?itemid=HFJD867&mode=normal/#!/dashboard
```

at this point, the dashboard page appears and I can't view the link. The state is being appended after the params.

here's route.config.ts

```
export default [
"$stateProvider",
"$urlRouterProvider",
($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {

    $urlRouterProvider.when("/", ["$state", ($state) => {
        $state.go("home");
    }]);

    $stateProvider
        .state("login",{
            url             :   "/login",
            controllerAs    :   "vm",
            controller      :   "loginCtrl",
            templateUrl     :   loginTemplateUrl
        })
        .state("home", {
            url:"",
            controller:"homeCtrl",
            controllerAs:"vm",
            resolve:{
                 "items":["homeService", (homeService) => {
                    return homeService.getItems();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state("dashboard",{
            url             :   "/dashboard",
            controllerAs    :   "vm",
            controller      :   "dashboardCtrl",
            templateUrl     :   dashboardTemplateUrl,
            resolve:{
                allItems:["dashboardService", (dashboardService) => {
                    return dashboardService.getAllItems();
                }]
            }
        })
   }
];
```

It seems that the problem is this, that is why it's appending the '/dashboard' at the end. by the way, when state goes to 'home' it will go to 'dashboard' state.

```
$urlRouterProvider.when("/", ["$state", ($state) => {
        $state.go("home");
    }]);
```

How can I prevent this from going to 'home' state when there is a parameter to the url.